# Excel VBA Copy Line Macro from row to range

Tags: excel, vba

My current VBA code pulls from one worksheet and splits the data into 2 based on a condition (What Value in Column A) It copys the entire row based upon my current code which is

UPDATE CODE:

```
Sub discoCopydata()
'DEFINES THE SHEETS AND THE RANGE USED FOR THE COPY PROCESS
Dim dataSource As Worksheet: Set dataSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Miscellaneous   Holds")
Dim dataTargetA As Worksheet: Set dataTargetA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CDN")
Dim dataTargetB As Worksheet: Set dataTargetB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("US")
Dim dataSourceRange As Range: Set dataSourceRange = dataSource _
.Range("A1:A" & dataSource.Cells(dataSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row)

' LOOP CAN BE ADJUSTED TO MULTIPLE CONDITIONS
For Each Cell In dataSourceRange
    'IS THE DATA FOR CAN?
    If Cell.Value = "CAN" = True Then
        dataTargetA.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow.Value _
        = Cell.EntireRow.Value
    'IS THIS US DATA?
    ElseIf Cell.Value = "US" Then
        dataTargetB.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow.Value _
        = Cell.EntireRow.Value
    End If
Next
```

End Sub
What I need to do is confine this to a range I.E. From A5:K1000 as that is the size of my imported data. Can I do that within the confines of my code. I could switch `Cell.EntireRow.Value` to `Cell.Range.Value` which should paste the data within a cell range correct?

Comment: Difficult to tell exactly what you weant: a single line of code doesn't provide much context.

Comment: Just updated the code, I think if I change Cell.EntireRow.Value to Cell.Range.Value it will work but I error : (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
If Cell.Value = "CAN" = True Then
    dataTargetA.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(1,11).Value _
    = Cell.Resize(1, 11).Value
```

Comment: At first this wasn't working, but I dropped the Cell.Resize to (1, 10).Value and it cleared the issue! Thank you Tim!